# Stop script from re-running on page refresh

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an aptitude test application. But during the test when I hit refresh button my script re-run and new question get displayed. I don't want to reshuffle my questions when the user hit the refresh button. I want to stop my PHP script running when the user hit the refresh button or go back and start the test again. The set of question should not change until and unless user answer all question and hit continue button.

```
<form name='form1' method='post' action='mmpi-test.php'>
                                                        <?php

@mysql_connect("localhost" ,"root","");

@mysql_select_db("epsychotherapist");

$querya = mysql_query("SELECT lq FROM `u_profile` WHERE Uid = '$Uid'");
//mysql_query($querya) ;
//$lq = '';
$rowa = mysql_fetch_array($querya);
$lq = $rowa['lq'];
//$lq = 10; 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mmpi` WHERE Id >'$lq' LIMIT 5");




 while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($query)):
    $q = $rows['Id'];
    $qus = $rows['Question'];
    echo" <p>&nbsp;</p>";
    echo "<div class='tab-pane active' id='profile'>
            <table class='table'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>&nbsp;$qus 
                        <td class='td-actions text-right'>

                                <div class='radio'>
                                    <label>
                                       <font color='#777'>True</font> <input type='radio' name = 'answer[$q]' value = '1'>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                       <font color='#777'>False</font> <input type='radio' name = 'answer[$q]' value = '0'>
                                    </label>
                                </div>



                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>";
    endwhile;
?>
<?php
$sql = "UPDATE u_profile SET lq='$q' WHERE Uid = '$Uid'" ;
                        mysql_query($sql);
                        $lq = $q;
                        $_SESSION['lq'] = $lq;
echo"
<button type='submit' name='next' class='btn btn-primary pull-right'>Continue >> $q $lq</button>
";

?> </form>
```

I am maintaing a session

```
<?php
/* Displays user information and some useful messages */
session_start();

// Check if user is logged in using the session variable
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
  $_SESSION['message'] = "You must log in before viewing your profile page!";
  //header("location: ../error.php");    
}
else {
    // Makes it easier to read
    $first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $Uid = $_SESSION['Uid'];
   // $active = $_SESSION['active'];
}
?>
```

Comment: So use same session management in first PHP code to check if user has started quiz. Also: `mysql_*`, `<font>` are deprecated and you use same ID in each loop iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The set of question should not change until and unless user answer all question and hit continue button."

I guess you have answered the question yourself.

### 1) Remember the question set once it has been generated.

Consider to create a new table in your database for storing someone's session which contains his/her own question set and there should be at least one indicator notices whether this question set has been created yet.

```
CREATE TABLE `TBL_question_set` (
  `userid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `question1` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `question2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `question3` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `question4` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `question5` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `createdyet` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
)
```

> Check the table at the top of your script by userid which you have
>   assigned to him/her (perhaps the session userid). If it exists, just
>   read them from the table instead of your own question db.

### 2) Now you should know when to clear the record of question set.

I think you are able to do it yourself to decide when to clear the record of question set.

> Perhaps when the session ID is different or the user has clicked the
>   'continue' button.

### 3) Hereby, I would like to mention something which maybe some of you are interested in

but a bit off-topic. When I start writing some PHP script to create my own member login system, like most of you, copy and paste from online demo code. And one day I discovered something is quite interesting but also could be very horrible that

> those example code usually determine if a user is in state of
>   'logged-in' by checking his/her $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 only.

Yes, it doesn't matter perhaps. As the session id will be expired after a period, however, if the user is deleted in your database and he/she should have no right to access your website anymore. At this period, he/she still could access your website which is not your expection.

Thus, I would recommend to add one more rule:

---

> When a user logins, check if the userid is still exist in your
>   database!!

---

Good luck.

Comment: that's a great solution but I have one question. how should I store the value of each question in the variable? this is a while loop so $qus value always get updated

Comment: It depends on how you design your table structure... e.g. Since 1st time there's no question set has been generated, thus you query the question set from your org. question set table; 2nd time or later, if the session userid still exists, you don't want the question set could be updated, thus you should query the question set from `TBL_question_set` which stored your last question set id or even question set order... try to write some new code to prove you get the idea, great time.